# I need a program for a wordcount

Tags: java, string, io, word-count

I need to figure out how to make a program that counts the words in a sentence that the user inputs. The user also inputs the length that each word must be. So, if the user inputs 5 letter words, and the sentence includes a 4 letter word; that word won't be counted.

This is all I have...

```
public class wordcount {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   int length = IO.readInt();
   String sentence = IO.readString();
   int full = sentence.length();
   int wordcount = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
   }
   System.out.print(wordcount);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Rather than asking for the entire function you should let us know what you have tried already, and which parts you do or don't understand.

Comment: i dont understand how to make the counter work, no matter what i put it always says 2

Comment: How many words in this setence are longer than 5 letters? Now describe (in English) how you figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
return sentence.split("\\s+").length;
```

Comment: That is insufficient. A specific number of characters per word may be requested when counting, according to OP.

Comment: @E_net4 yeah, but it's an interesting start

Comment: @MadProgrammer It may be interestingly simple, but we usually prefer to have a complete solution in an answer, don't you think?

Comment: @E_net4 not for homework, we need to teach our juniors how to fish, not give them fish ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will read counts for an input line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
    int length = scanner.nextInt();
    String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.close();

    int wordcount = 0;
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
       if(words[i].length() >= length ){
          wordcount++;
       }
   }
   System.out.print(wordcount);
}
```

}