# Word count program, trouble with counter

Tags: java, string, io, word-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need a program for a wordcount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945357/i-need-a-program-for-a-wordcount)

User inputs a sentence and a minimum length of each word, the program then has to count the number of words in the sentence that meet the length requirement.

I'm having trouble with my counter to store a word if it is above the required length.

Here's all I have. We can only use `String` and `IO`.

```
public class wordcount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int length = IO.readInt();
        String sentence = IO.readString();
        int y= 0;           
        for( int x= 0;x > sentence.length();x++){
            if(x>= length)
                y= y+1;
        }
        System.out.print(y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now you're comparing if your index is greater than the specified length, not the word at that index. Also, the loop will not be entered since your guard in the for loop checks if x > sentence.length(), when it should be <. Use "String[] words = sentence.split(" ");" to separate the sentence into a String array with one String per word. Loop through this array, checking if each word (words[x].length()) meets the requirement.